# Django-Allauth : no social buttons on account creation view?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I've installed django-allauth and activated Facebook/Instagram/Google/Twitter.

These are all visible and useable from the "login" view, but the "signup" view contains only the classic "email/password/confirmpassword" fields.

Looking at the [signup template](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/templates/account/signup.html), I see that there are no social accounts there.

This is confusing to me, are users supposed to create an account first with email, and *then* use their social accounts to login ? Why can't they just signup with their social accounts ?

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because, people can directly login using `social accounts` when you use **django-allauth**.

Once you hit on login using social accounts, It takes you through the process validates your socail accounts and let you log in.

Thats why there is no option for `signup` using  social accounts.

Comment: It looks like you are right, but isn't that counter intuitive ? If you are a user, you don't know you can use login directly, so you'd look for the "create account" feature. Also, it means that if you can't remember if you used facebook, twitter, google or your email last time, you might accidentally create multiple accounts while trying to login with each.

Comment: Yeah, I too am using it and I know it's confusing. But thats the way they have provided. You can have a look on my website `kodefork.com`.